# NSString concatenate on creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to concatenate 2 strings assigning the result to a new string.

Normally I would do this way:

```
NSString * s = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", str1, str2];
```

Now I wish s to be static

```
static NSString * s = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", str1, str2];
```

but compiler kick me with "Initializer element is not a compile-time..."

Is there any way to do this? I Googled a bit with no results and also I have not found answers on StackOverflow asking the question.

And what about using a short form like (in PHP)

```
$s = $str1.$str2;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: What i want to achieve is to have a config file like this (in PHP code)

```
define ("BASE_URL", "mysite.com/");
define ("SERVICE_URL1", BASE_URL."myservice1.php?param1=value1");
define ("SERVICE_URL2", BASE_URL."myservice2.php?param2=value2");
```

I prefer to have all configurations strings in 1 file and i found usefull static strings in objective c. Just want to put 2 usefull thing together :)

EDIT2: There's no metter if i obtain this with defines, but the NSString way is preferred and i use static just beacause const make me some compilation problems i haven't solved yet

Comment: Where is all this code? In a method? Class level static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this way:

```
#define kBaseURL @"mysite.com/"
static NSString *kServiceUrl1 = kBaseURL @"myservice1.php?param1=value1";
static NSString *kServiceUrl2 = kBaseURL @"myservice2.php?param2=value2";
```

thanks all.

now the question is
wich one i have to accept as right answer? I mean, mine is the solution, but I would never have got there without your help guys

Comment: Definetly Vitali's: First he init's a static with an if instead of dispatch_once() and then he copied my answer in an update. This has to be honored. ;-)

Comment: i have red the answer linked by him and basically is no wrong, but the if and the dispatch_once solutions is for a method usage and not what i need exactly. My solution don't need a method so i'll accept mine, but put an up sign to yours since them was useful :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this code for creating static `s`:

```
static NSString * s = nil;
if (!s)
    s = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", str1, str2];
```

Also for concatenating two string you case use such code: `NSString *s = [str1 stringByAppendingString: str2];`

**UPDATED:**
You can concat static string by putting them one by one.
Example:

```
#define STR1 @"First part" @" Second part"
#define STR2 @"Third part " STR1
NSLog(@"%@", STR2);
```

This cole will print `Third part First part Second part`

Comment: why the if(!s) is needed? cannot i simply do s = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", str1, str2];?

Comment: Ok, and what about the short form? is there any literal way? the problem is that i have all the static strings in an .h file and compiler don't allow me to do if inside

Comment: @Alex75, are str1 and str2 constants? How do you define them?

Comment: @VitalyS. they are static NSString as well. I can also use #define if needed, but i think there is the same problem

Comment: Your code is not useful. A message is sent, a result is /computed/ at /runtime/, every time it is executed, but you want to have it static? Probably you mismatched static and immutable. If you want to create a string at compile time, look at my answer.

Comment: @Alex75, I've just updated my answer with details about static NSStrings

Answer (score 1):

I think below lines may help:

```
NSString *str1 = @"String1";
NSString *str2 = @"String2";
NSString *combinedStr = [str1 stringByAppendingString:str2];
```

Comment: How does this help? They state they want it to be static so this is incorrect where is the static? -1 I will remove if corrected, and I have tested this it doesn't just mean adding static.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a define, it is pretty simple:

```
#define A @"a"
#define B @"b"
…
static NSString *ab = A B; // or: @"A" @"B"
```

You can always concatenate string literals with a single space.

But something very important has to happen to use defines. What's wrong with computing it non-static or compute it once?

BTW: You should use `dispatch_once()` and *not* `if`. For the reasons you can search "dispatch_once" on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind compiling Objective-C++ code, you could simply change the extension from .m to .mm, by default XCode compiles according to file type, and this is valid in Objective-C++

Comment: Really don't know wich are the difference between OBJC and OBJC++ and wich is the advantage to use one instead the other, but for now i'll go with OBJC since this is an almost finished project for my company