# How concatenate a 2 constants

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having a few global variables declared in an `NSObject` class.

```
NSString *const SAT_NAME=@"http://you.com";
NSString *const DOMAIN= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@name/",SAT_NAME,nil];
```

I want to append the `DOMAIN` as shown (`http://you.com/name/`), but it does not work. How can i fix this ?

Comment: What do you mean by “it does not work”?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString concatenate on creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628472/nsstring-concatenate-on-creation)

Comment: Unrelated to issue - why are you passing `nil` at the end of `stringWithFormat`? That's not needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create constant NSString by concatenating strings in Obj-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060139/how-to-create-constant-nsstring-by-concatenating-strings-in-obj-c)

Comment: add a / before %@ it should be /%@name or add it after .com like .com/ and remove nil from your second line.

Comment: @johnykumar No, the slash needs to be between the `%@` and `name` like: `@"%@/name/"`.

Comment: maybe it depends upon its url m just clarifying his issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *const SAT_NAME=@"http://you.com";
NSString *const DOMAIN= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@name/",SAT_NAME,nil];
```

Look at the format string. It starts with %@. The %@ is replaced with "http://you.com". Now if you use copy and paste, you see that the result is

```
http://you.comname/
```

I don't quite see what you think the nil is good for. There is no formatting for it, so it is just ignored.